# html, css, javascript - show/hide divs - one is shown than another should be hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create show/hide div's.
It is my code: jsfiddle.net/b60b34h1

But it don't works like I want.
I want that when "press button2" pressed than another div's should hidden. 
It should show only one div.

Can You help me?
Thanks

Comment: please update your question properly and if possible add snippet in it for better understanding

Comment: check jsfiddle link - than its clear - I think.
P.S. Sorry for my english.

Comment: which div you want to hide when button2 is pressed?

Comment: All another div's. It should only one div visible. When next button pressed than previous should hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this method

```
function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    var openDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("unhidden");
    if(openDiv[0]!=undefined){
          openDiv[0].className = 'hidden';
    }

    if (item) {
      item.className='unhidden';
    }
  }
```

Please find working snippet

```js
function unhide(divID,currentLink) {
     var activeLink = document.getElementsByClassName("thick");
       if(activeLink[0]!=undefined){
          activeLink[0].className = 'btn btn-line-black';
    }
    var currentLink = document.getElementById(currentLink);
    currentLink.className = 'thick btn btn-line-black';
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    var openDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("unhidden");
    if(openDiv[0]!=undefined){
          openDiv[0].className = 'hidden';
    }
    if (item) {
      item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
    }
  }
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
.unhidden { display: block; }

.thick{
  font-weight: bold;
   color :red!important;
}

a:after{
font-weight: bold;
}

.btn{
  color :green;
}
.btn-line-black{
  border :1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 
</script>

<div>
  <p><a id="link1" class="btn btn-line-black" href="javascript:unhide('button1','link1');">press button1</a> <a id="link2" class="btn btn-line-black" href="javascript:unhide('button2','link2');">press button2</a> <a id="link3" class="btn btn-line-black" href="javascript:unhide('button3','link3');">press button3</a></p>
  <div class="hidden" id="button1">
    <h3>button1</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<div class="hidden" id="button2">
    <h3>button2</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<div class="hidden" id="button3">
    <h3>button3</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: we cant edit your site directly. if you get a approach try to implement same in your site

Comment: please see the updated answer. You havent provided the one div with unhidded class by default. Hence you were getting this error "Cannot set property 'className' of undefined".

Comment: just provide the class unhidden to button1 div it will work

Comment: @online123 great :)

Comment: Cen You help me again:
how to make css style for button "div active". For examle: when button2 pressed than button2 is bold. Than wen button3 pressed -> button3 is bold, and button2 in no more bold. http://zkm.org.pl/aaa-div-test/

Comment: Did u unmark this answer ? It would b grt if i can get a reason i would luv to improve. You can apply a class which bolder the text and similar fashion you can toggle that class

Comment: .thick {
    font-weight: bold;
}
and you can do like openDiv[0].classList.remove('thick')

Comment: And item.className = 'unhidden thick'

Comment: Can you make it in jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure will make changes and let u know

Comment: When can I expect it?

Comment: For no-active buttons I have this classes: btn and btn-line-black.
How to make active button with the three classes: thick, btn and btn-line-black? And no-active back to classes: btn and btn-line-black?

Comment: Is possible that one div is unhidden on site load and in for examle 5second it changes to another div? But than no mor changes - only wia buttons. I need this becose I need to preload images in my gallery. Because at the moment I can view only one category of images. When I preload all images than it should work with my images categories.

Comment: Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to hide the div that is shown...
Then show the div which correspond to the passed id, right?

This can be written just like this:

```js
  function unhide(divID) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('unhidden')[0].className = "hidden";
    document.getElementById(divID).className = "unhidden";
  }
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
.unhidden { display: block; }
```

```html
<div>
  <p><a href="javascript:unhide('button1');">press button1</a> <a href="javascript:unhide('button2');">press button2</a> <a href="javascript:unhide('button3');">press button3</a></p>
  <div class="unhidden" id="button1">
    <h3>button1</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<div class="hidden" id="button2">
    <h3>button2</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<div class="hidden" id="button3">
    <h3>button3</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ` on line 525. That is *stupid* WordPress who adds some `<p>&nbsp;</p>` on empty lines. Remove the empty line before `</script>`

Comment: You currently use my solution, and it works now... Event if you still have the same error in console. [Printscreen](http://s1208.photobucket.com/user/Bes7weB/media/wp-error_zpslgoifvao.jpg.html)

Comment: Now your `<p>` issue is fixed. Bravo! And you still use my solution... Could you re-accept my answer? (lol) Because, it not just to have the points... You actually indicate a wrong solution to other readers right now. Proof: If you input this : `console.log( $("#post-1587").find("script").text() );` in the console of this website : http://zkm.org.pl/aaa-div-test2/ You'll see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById('button' + divID);
    if (item) {
      item.className = 'unhidden';

      // hidden other divs
      for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        if (i != divID) {
          document.getElementById('button' + i).className = 'hidden';
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.unhidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="unhide(1)">press button1</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="unhide(2)">press button2</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="unhide(3)">press button3</a></p>
  <div class="unhidden" id="button1">
    <h3>button1</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden" id="button2">
    <h3>button2</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden" id="button3">
    <h3>button3</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```